# GraphQL Prisma - use orderBy on nested relationships

Tags: graphql, prisma

I am fairly new to GraphQL Prisma combo, I cannot seem to order nested relationships without error because the only available orderBy fields are regarding the ID.

My intended goal in the playground would be to create a query that looks similar to the following:

```
getPosts{
  connections(orderBy: "text_asc"){
   id
   text
  }
}
```

**Resolver**

```
getPosts(parent, args, ctx, info){
  return ctx.db.query.posts({}, info)
}
```

**Data Model**

```
type Post {
  id: ID! @id
  isPublished: Boolean! @default(value: false)
  title: String!
  text: String!
  connections: [Connection!]! @relation(name: "ClientConnect")
}

type Link {
  id: ID! @id
  text: String!
  url: String!
}

type Connection {
  id: ID! @unique @id
  client: Link @relation(name: "LinkConnect")
}
```

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this one? @nicholasbydesign

Comment: @JoimeeCajandab I have not, and from my understanding of Prisma 1 documentation this is not possible until Prisma 2.